# SQL query SELECT Data From One column, Split into two depending on YEAR, remove null

Tags: mysql, sql, null, group-by

I need help with splitting a column in two, depending on which year the data is from.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH,

(SELECT hwater 
 FROM test 
 WHERE      (ID = A.ID) 
    AND (year = 2015)) AS `2015`,

(SELECT hwater 
 FROM test 
 WHERE      (ID = A.ID) 
    AND (year = 2016)) AS `2016`

FROM test AS A 
WHERE A.year = 2015 OR A.year = 2016
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad580/1)

Column 2015 will be populated for the first 9 months, while column 2016 is null, After the second 9 months 2016 will be populated and 2015 Null I Would like to have 2016 on the same row as 2015 as shown below.

```
month   2015    2016
1       13      65
2       22      67
3       30      69
4       37      74
5       43      84
6       49      91
7       52      91
8       60      96
9       60      102
```

I tried GROUP BY Month, this resulted in displaying only results for 2015, while 2016 is NULL

The plan is to use this data as an array for an area chart to visually compare gradients.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some sample data producing the expected result would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CASE expression:

```
SELECT MONTH,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2015  THEN hwater ELSE 0 END) as `2015`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2016  THEN hwater ELSE 0 END) as `2016`       

FROM test AS A 
WHERE A.year = 2015 OR A.year = 2016
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad580/6)</kbd>

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.